# Algorithm to sort rows and cols by similarity

Tags: python, excel, algorithm, sorting, similarity

I fell across [a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sGZ6HQcY0lwM902-6vfrASlyDOeDeSQ-1l0EBBjobFg/edit?usp=sharing) that explains a method to sort both rows and columns of a matrix that contains binary data so that the number of changes between consecutive rows and cols is minimzed.

For example, starting with:

[image: initial table]

After 15 manual steps described in the tabs of the spreadsheed, the following table is obtained:

[image: final result]

I would like to know:

1. what is the common name of this algorithm or method ?
2. how to apply it to larger table (where 2^n would overflow...)
3. how to generalize it to non binary data, for example using Levenshtein distance ?
4. if there is any link to code (Excel VBA, Python, ...) already implementing this (otherwise I'll write it ... )

Thanks !

Comment: This is euclidean hamiltonian path in {0,1}^n; I think there might be constant-factor approximation algorithms since hampath is closely related to TSP (both hampath and TSP are np-hard for general graphs), and we have approximation algorithms for TSP, but don't expect to solve it optimally - although I'm not entirely sure that a hardness proof for this specific space exists, I'd be surprised if this was in P. I don't know what VBA can do, so I can't tell you whether you can implement an approximation algorithm there.

Comment: Having a second look, the distance is actually not euclidean, but the Hamming distance; I don't know hardness proofs or approximation algorithms for that one, but they probably exist.

Comment: Related: [Gray codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), also available as n-ary variants.

Comment: I was actually wrong; this isn't hampath, it's TSP without returning to the source, which is the TSP path problem (possibly referred to as TSPP in the literature). I also could've added that for non-binary coordinates, your problem is exactly euclidean TSPP; see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501634/traveling-salesman-without-return-and-with-given-start-and-end-cities).

Comment: I have to say, strictly speaking, this "question" is probably a poor fit for the Stack Overflow format. I mean, it's got multiple subquestions (which is discouraged), those component questions are arguably not *programming* questions (so off-topic), or are too broad (answering the question properly would require writing way too much). Despite all that, it's an *interesting* question, and it's cool to see that spreadsheet!

Comment: To answer subquestion 2: If you use Python to extract the data and then work purely in Python, you won't have overflow because Python has arbitrary-precision integers built-in.

Answer (score 3):

You can represent each row by a vector `L = [1, 1, 0, ... 1]`, and then define the distance between two lines `d(L0, L1)` by the number of elements at corresponding positions which are different between `L0` and `L1`. This is known as the binary [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). If you had non-binary data, you would just extend your definition of distance and yes, Levenshtein distance would be an option.

Once you have distance well-defined, the rest of your problem is minimizing distance between consecutive rows. This is exactly the [Traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which is known to be NP-hard(http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/jyrki/Paper/EKP85.pdf).

The direct solution (visiting all permutations) is O(n!), but you can do better easily by using dynamic programming, for example [Held–Karp_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm). There are also approximate algorithms, such as the [Nearest_neighbour_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm) which quickly computes a non-optimal solution.

Finally, for implementations you can easily google "traveling salesman excel/python" and find many tutorials and examples.